# RDLC Expression to convert seconds in hh:mm:ss

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

need a expression to convert seconds into hh:mm:ss to use in a texbox of a local report (ASP.NET with Report Viewer)

Answer (score 1):

This works even if hour part is >24hrs.

```
=right("0" & int(sum(Fields!Total_Login_Seconds.Value)/3600),2) & ":" 
& right("0" & int((sum(Fields!Total_Login_Seconds.Value) Mod 3600)/60),2) & ":" 
& right("0" & (sum(Fields!Total_Login_Seconds.Value) Mod 3600) Mod 60,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a vb syntax code to make calculations within the report, choose report textbox value property and write your vb code there